# Whats wrong in the syntax for image srcset

Tags: css, html, image

am trying to achieve to display a normal and hi-resolution image on the same view port size. like if i have rendered the page in low resolution phone which is of 550px it should show a low pixel image and at hi-resolution supported phones like IPhone it should show the hi-resolution image but it doesn't works

```
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/308367/cat-500.jpg"
    srcset="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/308367/cat-500.jpg 550w,
            https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/308367/cat-1000.jpg 2x 550w,
            https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-1x.png 1024w, 
            https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-2x.png 2x 1024w"  alt="imgsrcsettestimage">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `2x` and `1024w` both in same option. You should either use the `2x` (or any `x`) or use the `1024w` (or any `w`).

In short, you can't mix **density** (`x`) and **width** (`w`). So you should modify your code to use any one of these based on your actual requirements.

**Edit:**

Apparently, your required code should be like this:

```
<img src="s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/308367/cat-500.jpg"

     srcset="s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/308367/cat-500.jpg 550w,
             webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-1x.png 1024w, 
             webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-2x.png 2048w" 

             alt="imgsrcsettestimage">
```

I hope it fixes your problem.

Comment: I need the "cat-500.jpg" for low resolution devices at 550w and cat-1000.jpg for hi-resolution mobiles. also width of 1024w low relsolution devices image-1x.png and hi-resolution tablets image-2x.png. it is not triggering such a way.
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/308367/cat-500.jpg" srcset="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/308367/cat-500.jpg 550w, https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/308367/cat-1000.jpg 550w, https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-1x.png 1024w, https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-2x.png 1024w"  alt="imgsrcsettestimage">

Comment: @krish you can use density in srcset and then also give sizes attribute

Comment: @krish or simply have with attribute, with double the width in for 2x devices, i have updated the code, tell me if it works